Vitest error: SyntaxError: invalid arguments
I am trying to test a component that has vue-i18n translations in it, i have been using the plugin in all my tests however this particular component test gives me an error: SyntaxError: invalid arguments
I am wondering what im doing wrong here since i used this plugin for everything but this one is failing
import { expect, test, beforeEach, vi } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import Filters from "@/libs/quandago/components/filters/Filters.vue"
import { setActivePinia, createPinia } from "pinia";
import { createTestingPinia } from "@pinia/testing";
import i18n from "@/i18n"


test("it renders", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    setActivePinia(createPinia());
  });
  const wrapper = mount(Filters, {
    global: {
      stubs: ["vue-i18n", "i18n"],
      plugins: [createTestingPinia({ createSpy: vi.fn }), i18n]
    },
    props: {
      filters: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    }
  })
  expect(wrapper)
})

 **FAIL**  src/components/tests/Filters.spec.ts > it renders
SyntaxError: Invalid arguments
❯ node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.mjs:559:48

